# Funny interference in worldflags vs smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

Any idea of how the definitions of the flags with ornaments (in the interesting [worldflags](https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/contrib/worldflags/doc/worldflags.pdf) package) are disturbed ?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,smartdiagram,worldflags}

\begin{document}

    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{
        \worldflag{CH},                 
        \worldflag{GB},
        \worldflag{US},
        \worldflag{FR},
        \worldflag{IT},
        \worldflag{BR},
        \large{Credit risk increases, spreads increase}
    }
            
\end{document}
```

**Edit jan12th 2022**
I contacted the author who kindly responded that the next release will take into account this case of `TikZ` nesting.

[image]

Comment: `\worldflag` is a `tikzpicture` and nesting it in another `tikzpicture` is bound to have side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\worldflag` makes a `tikzpicture`, so I think you're effectively nesting `tikzpicture`s here, which is generally a bad idea. It often leads to problems with options from the outer `tikzpicture` being inherited by the inner one. In this particular case it looks like a `rounded corners` options is the culprit, if you do for example `\tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{BR}` it looks better. I don't know whether this is a *good* solution though.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,smartdiagram,worldflags}

\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{descriptive items y sep=2}
    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{CH},                 
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{GB},
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{US},
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{FR},
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{IT},
        \tikzset{/tikz/rounded corners=0}\worldflag{BR},
        {\large Credit risk increases, spreads increase}
    }
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: T. Insane :) Respect.

Comment: All the flags are available as `pic`'s - see "Flags as picture elements within a TikZ-picture" in the manual. I do not know if this is useful in a `smartdiagram`!?

Comment: @hpekristiansen I think (haven't checked) that the entries for the diagram are placed directly in nodes, so no, I don't think it would help.

Comment: @hpekristiansen thanks for the useful tip. I'll have to use flags extensively in TikZ soon.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the safer option, when trying to nest Ti*k*Z things, is to use boxes. In the example below, I wrote a macro that puts the flag in a box called `\flagXX`. That one is safe to use in nodes.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,smartdiagram,worldflags}
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxflag}{m}{%
    \expandafter\newsavebox\csname flag#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\sbox\expandafter{\csname flag#1\endcsname}{\worldflag{#1}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\useflag}{m}{%
    \expandafter\usebox\expandafter{\csname flag#1\endcsname}%
}
\boxflag{CH}
\boxflag{GB}
\boxflag{US}
\boxflag{FR}
\boxflag{IT}
\boxflag{BR}
\begin{document}

    \smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{
        \useflag{CH},
        \useflag{GB},
        \useflag{US},
        \useflag{FR},
        \useflag{IT},
        \useflag{BR},
        \large{Credit risk increases, spreads increase}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! +1. I already validated Torbjørn's answer but yours has the virtue of automating the patch. I contacted the author and future update will handle this.