# How to draw an equilateral triangle with a solid line inside it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I know how to draw a triangle like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Triangle 2
\node at (2,-1) {triangle 2};
\draw (0,0)--(2,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{};
\draw (2,0)--(2,2) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowR};
\draw (0,0)--(2,2) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowR};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But, here is the figure I wanna draw:

> [image]

An equilateral triangle with a solid line inside it, could anyone help me in this drawing please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First nobody can help you since you did not provide how `\arrowL` and `\arrowR` are defiend.

I also do not know what you do not understand with the code given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631211/drawing-triangles-with-different-directions-and-having-bold-arrows-on-sides/631234?noredirect=1#comment1574200_631234).

You can achieve this triangle by simple extend it by one more line using the corresponding tikz syntax `\draw`.

EDIT: As mentioned by Rmano this first version is nesting tikz enviroments. So it is better to use the second version with decorations.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrowL}{
    \tikz \draw[latex-] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}
\newcommand{\arrowR}{
    \tikz \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(8,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (4,4)--(8,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (0,0)--(4,4) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (4,4)--(4,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{};  

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...and with labels:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arrowL}{
    \tikz \draw[latex-] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}
\newcommand{\arrowR}{
    \tikz \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(8,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (4,4)--(8,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (0,0)--(4,4) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{\arrowL};
        \draw (4,4)--(4,0) node[sloped,pos=0.5]{};  

% nodes
 \node[left] at (0,0) {$v$};
 \node[right] at (8,0) {$v$};
 \node[above] at (4,4) {$v$};
 \node[below] at (4,0) {$b$};
 \node[above] at (2,2) {$a$};
 \node[above] at (6,2) {$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

a version using decorations:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style={postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrowreversed{latex}}}},
    arrow2/.style={postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow{latex}}}},
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        ] 
        
        \draw[arrow] (0,0)--(8,0);      
        \draw[arrow] (4,4)--(8,0);
        \draw[arrow] (0,0)--(4,4);
        \draw (4,4)--(4,0);  
    
    % nodes
    \node[left] at (0,0) {$v$};
    \node[right] at (8,0) {$v$};
    \node[above] at (4,4) {$v$};
    \node[below] at (4,0) {$b$};
    \node[above] at (2,2) {$a$};
    \node[above] at (6,2) {$a$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am in document class

Comment: Hmmm... It works in this case, but you are nesting `tikz` environments, which is highly dangerous. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629435/funny-interference-in-worldflags-vs-smartdiagram --- as soon as you add options, the internal arrow can do strange things. I suggest using decorations here.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, I did not realizd that I am actually nesting tikz. I added a version with decorations.

Comment: The version the OP gives look better but maybe just because the lines are thicker and the arrows bigger?

Answer (score 3):

For an equilateral triangle, with this code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %   Triangle 1
        
        %\draw (0,0)--(2,0)--(60:2)--(0,0)--cycle;
        \draw (2,0)--(0,0) node[midway,below] () {$b$};
        \draw (2,0)--(1,1.732) node[midway,right] () {$a'$};
        \draw (1,1.732)--(0,0) node[midway,left] () {$a'$};
        \draw[-latex] (2,0)--(1,0);
        \draw[-latex] (2,0)--(1.5,0.866);
        \draw[-latex] (1,1.732)--(.5,0.866);
        \draw (1,1.732)--(1,0);
        \node[below] at (0,0) () {$v$};
        \node[below] at (2,0) () {$v$};
        \node[above] at (1,1.732) () {$v$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

you have the output:

[image]

If you want only the equilateral triangle, with this code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0)--(2,0)--(60:2)--(0,0)--cycle;
        \draw (1,1.732)--(1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you have this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution with `tkz-euclide`. You can choose between the following triangles:
[image]
equilateral
half or  two one
pythagore or pythagoras or egyptian
school
golden or sublime
euclid or euclide
gold
cheops
two angles
isosceles right

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tkzSetUpLine[line width=.4pt,color=teal]
\tikzset{arrow/.style={
         decoration={markings,
         mark= at position .5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}}}}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)    \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,M)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefTriangle[egyptian](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I take the same code but to inverse the triangle I wrote `B,A` instead of `A,B`idem for the arrow.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tkzSetUpLine[line width=.4pt,color=teal]
\tikzset{arrow/.style={
         decoration={markings,
         mark= at position .5 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}}}}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)    \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](B,A B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,M)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](B,A) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B)    \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegments[arrow,postaction={decorate}](A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,M)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the tip of the triangle on the right to be its base, I want to preserve the direction of the arrows, I think the triangle you inverted is not the one I am giving above.... am I correct?

Comment: No the second triangle is to show you that you can draw some triangles defined in `tkz-euclide`. Now you can  do anything. I add some codes to show you how modify ...